# How do I center a single line of text in a tcolorbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

This one is really stumping and it seems like it should be so simple. I'm attempting to center lines at the end of a `tcolorbox`. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[A4]{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{peas}{HTML}{d4e79e}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=450pt, halign=left, colframe=darkgray, colback=peas, 
boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm]
Please Read Carefully...

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\\
\vspace{5mm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:
[image: The reality]

I'm trying to find a way to do this:

[image: The Dream]

I've tried to use the old `\begin{center}` and `\center` to no avail. I've also tried to make a table within the color box to center but since the box is a float (I believe) I cannot define column widths. Any advice on a simple way to achieve my dream?

Comment: A blank line and `\centering` before the text should suffice.,

Comment: The center environment works fine for me.

Comment: Well would you look at that, it works! It's astonishing how many incorrect uses of \centering I invented over the past several hours. 

You folks are fantastic!

Comment: The option for selecting ISO A4 paper is `a4paper`, not `A4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `\hfil` twice:

```
{\hfil
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\hfil}
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{peas}{HTML}{d4e79e}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=450pt, halign=left, colframe=darkgray, colback=peas, 
boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm]
Please Read Carefully...

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\\
\vspace{5mm}

{\hfil
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\hfil}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

you get:

[image]

Comment: This also worked! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment or try a `center lower` and`lower separated=false` version, if the `lower box` is not designed to be used for other requests:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{peas}{HTML}{d4e79e}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=450pt, halign=left, colframe=darkgray, colback=peas, 
boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm]
Please Read Carefully...


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}

% Again, with center lower etc. 

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=450pt, halign=left, colframe=darkgray, colback=peas,% parbox=false,
boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm,center lower, lower separated=false]
Please Read Carefully...


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\tcblower
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```